# Gson.toJson not converting boolean values from object

Tags: json, gson, converters

Google's Gson.toJson(Object src) not converting boolean values. 
For example, My Java object is say:

```
class MyObj { 
    private String name;
    private boolean teen;

    //getter,setter ommitted...
  }

MyObj obj = new MyObj();
obj.setName("Me");
obj.isTeen(false);

Gson.toJson(obj);
```

While converting this object it's writing like this

```
MyObj { "name" : "Me" }
```

boolean is missing even though there was a value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Gson doesn't serialize the fields only if the field is defined as `transient` or `static`.

If you haven't defined the boolean field as static or transient, json should have that field.

I am not sure how you are setting the value to boolean field using `isTeen()` method. It should give compilation error unless you have non-trivial "is" method for boolean field. The "is" method is basically an equivalent of "get" method for String/other fields. Typically, it won't be used to set the value.

I have just provided the full code with getters and setters. Please check whether this works.

```
public class MyObj {

    private String name;

    private boolean teen;
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public boolean isTeen() {
        return teen;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public void setTeen(boolean teen) {
        this.teen = teen;
    }
}
```

**Main Method:-**

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

        Gson gson = new Gson();

        MyObj obj = new MyObj();
        obj.setName("Me");
        obj.setTeen(false);

        System.out.println(gson.toJson(obj));
    }
```

**Output:-**

```
{"name":"Me","teen":false}
```

The interesting point is that even if you don't set any value for boolean field. It will take the default as **false** and the generated JSON will have false.

Comment: Yes that was a type about the isTeen() method. It was indeed setTeen() method. I didn't actually copy that from my code base. Just wrote directly from here. The strange thing is, I didn't change my code but it started working after a day. Not sure what did I miss, as I was very puzzled when it didn't work for the first time.

Comment: ok good. Would you like to accept the answer just for reassuring that there is no problem in the code or api. Sometimes when you break complex things into smaller pieces, it could provide some clue that the problem could be in some other place.